# How to get system boot time with millisecond precision?

Tags: python, time, pyaudio

I'm using pyaudio to map some time-sensitive information and as it returns it's input buffer time as seconds since uptime, i.e. `{'input_buffer_adc_time': 4349.296026752835}`, I have to calculate it's `datetime` manually. Ideally, I would like to know chunk start time with about 1ms precision, so I can't use `psutil.boot_time()` as it'll drop milliseconds completely, i.e.

```
In [189]: psutil.boot_time()
Out[189]: 1626895334.0
```

I've tried reading uptime from `proc`, like this

```
def uptime_delta():
    """
    Get delta between system uptime and unix timestamp
    :return: float of unix timestamp delta, result of unixtimestamp now - uptime
    """
    with open("/proc/uptime") as f:
        uptime = float(f.read().split()[0])
        now = datetime.now().timestamp()
        return now - uptime
```

but it gives very inconsistent results

```
In [173]: uptime_delta()
Out[173]: 1626895334.92133

In [174]: uptime_delta()
Out[174]: 1626895334.913
```

in this example it's 8ms of difference between two runs, but I've seen 20+ ms difference.

So far I've settled on using

```
In [186]: mean([uptime_delta() for x in range(1000)])
Out[186]: 1626895334.9171343
```

which is consistent, but takes 16.6 ms to calculate and overall seems like a stupid idea. On top of that I'm running this on raspberry Pi, which doesn't have stable power or network, meaning that if I just calculate it once at runtime, there's a good chance NTP will sync up somewhere mid run, messing everything up.

Are there any better ways to figure out when boot time or pyaudio's chunk time with decent precision?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `time.monotonic()`

Reading `/proc/uptime` 10000 times with the function above gave me up to 10ms of deviation. With `time.time() - time.monotonic()` it's under 0.006ms